# Can not find the word I need, please help if you know it

Tags: single-word-requests

The word is for a part or accessory made by the same brand as the product it works with, and is only available from that brand manufacturer. For example, a Nikon or Canon camera has a cable made specifically for that brand and model camera. In my mind, I'm picturing the word starts with the letter "p", but at this point I'm not sure.

Comment: Patent? Proprietary?

Comment: That's it!!!! Oh my goodness thank you!!! I have been trying to figure that out for the last 5 hours lol. I was even looking through a dictionary at all words starting with "p" for a while. Thank you so much for solving this for me :)

Comment: You're welcome! I posted a second option just as you posted your comment. If anyone's interested, the OP chose 'proprietary'.

Comment: I might use the term *own brand* to identify a part for a Nikon camera made by Nikon, and *off brand* to identify a part for a Nikon camera made by another manufacturer.  To my devious mind even Sony might make a *proprietary* part for a Nikon camera though would have to do so without infringing any of Nikon's IP rights.  But my suggestions begin with the letter *o* ...